# Word getting image clicked by mouse [Visual Basic]

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a basic user form with 100 images (10x10) inside a multipage frame,
all images are renamed after their positions (top left 00 and bottom right 99)

so instead of making imagexx_click() function for each image I want a way to detect which image (or an object) is clicked

Whats tried;

I tried to use MultiPage1_Click() to detect but that only detects for the multipage, if user clicks an image inside it, it doesn't detect

I tried to use eventhandler with application as documented [here](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/word-powerpoint-outlook-and-other-office-products/23313-capture-mouse-click-event-paragraph-ms-word.html)
but I had no luck with both [BeforeDoubleClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.beforedoubleclick.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event and [SelectionChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.selectionchange.aspx) event

I even tried to reference system and implement a mouse click event

So what would be an easy solution for this

Comment: Is it a control array? if so then you can use the .index method for the object, otherwise if i's all separate images then that complicates matters a lot more.

Comment: Well it is all seperate images, think of em as seats in a theater that are configurable :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class module clsImg:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents img As MSForms.Image

Private Sub img_Click()
    Debug.Print "single - " & img.Name
End Sub

Private Sub img_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Debug.Print "double - " & img.Name
End Sub
```

Your Form module:

```
Private col As New Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim o As clsImg, c As Object

    For Each c In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(c) = "Image" Then
            Set o = New clsImg
            Set o.img = c
            col.Add o
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Ive been trying to overcome this for a great +6 hours
Now with this.. I can complete my little project of making a movie program with configurable theater sizes :)